# Vue - npm install vue-custom-element giving Npm error

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vuejs2

I have built a webpack-simple vue starter app.
I then tried to installed this. `npm install vue-custom-element --save`.
I am getting below error and don't have any idea whats happening here. Why its going for document-register-element package. Was working fine till 2 days before.
Please help for same.
[image]

Comment: I think your problem has to do with the line regarding `sleep`.

Comment: Are you running this on cmd.exe? Try using a terminal multiplexor, which would support few nix commands such as sleep, which may be the cause of your problem

Comment: Well the issue has been found. Its `document-register-element` package which was last released 3 days ago and is an dependency for the package I want to install `vue-custom-element`. Problem is doesn't exist if we use Git bash but with npm. The Author is testing this and will probably move `document-register-element` to devDependency.